# Compositions of finite maps between quasi-projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I already asked this as a part 2 of a two-part question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955177/vol-1-shafarevich-two-questions-about-finite-maps), but didn't get a response to this part, so I'm posting it again. Apologies in advance.

Say $X,Y,Z$ are quasi-projective varieties. Let me recall the definition of finite maps in this setting (following Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry").

> A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of quasi-projective varieties is finite if any point $y\in Y$ has an affine neighbourhood $U$ such that $V = f^{-1}(U)$ is affine and $f:V\rightarrow U$ is a finite map between affine varieties.

Under this definition, is it true that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ are finite maps between quasi-projective varieties, then so is their composition $g \circ f$? If so, how does one prove it?

I can see that this is true for affine varieties, but I don't see it in the quasi-projective case.

Comment: What's stopping you from going from the affine case to the quasi-projective case?

Comment: This is where I'm stuck. Say $z\in Z$ has open affine neighbourhood $W$ such that $V:= g^{-1}(W)$ is affine and $g|_V$ is finite. I don't know if it is true that $U:=f^{-1}(V)$ is affine. If it were, one could probably argue (not sure about this) that $f|_U$ is finite.

Comment: That's true. What you need to do is prove that if a map $f:X\to Y$ is finite and $Y$ is affine, then $X$ is also affine and the coordinate ring of $X$ is module-finite over the coordinate ring of $Y$ (this shows that for a finite map, the preimage of *any* affine open is again an affine with coordinate ring module-finite over the coordinate ring of that affine open).

Comment: @KReiser : Thanks for your reply! But I don't understand how the first claim you suggested would prove that the preimage of any affine open is again affine. To be precise, assume that we have a finite $f: X\rightarrow Y$ ($X$, $Y$ quasiprojective) and an affine open $V\subset Y$. Presumably, you mean to apply the claim to the preimage $U := f^{-1}(V)$. However, I don't know that $f$ restricted to $U$ is a finite map. Is it? If not, I don't see how to apply the claim.

Comment: It is. Given a point $y\in V\subset Y$, let $N$ be an affine open neighborhood of $y\in Y$ guaranteed by the definition of finiteness with preimage $M\subset X$. If $N\subset V$, we're done; if not, we can find a function $g$ on $N$ and $h$ on $V$ so that $D(g)\subset N$ is equal to $D(h)\subset V$. Then the coordinate ring of $f^{-1}(D(g))$ is the coordinate ring of $M$ localized at the pullback of $g$, which is again module-finite over the coordinate ring of $D(g)$. (The proof that we can find such a function is known as Nike's trick.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now the second part. But I'm still not able to prove your original claim: if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is finite and $Y$ affine, then $X$ is affine. I think the claim reduces to showing that if there are finitely many regular functions $h_1,\ldots,h_n$ on $Y$ such that  $\bigcup_i D(h_i) = Y$ (and hence their pullbacks $\tilde{h}_i$ satsify $\bigcup_i D(\tilde{h}_i)=X$ (in fact there is some linear combination $\sum_i g_i \tilde{h}_i$ which is invertible on $X$)), and if each $D(\tilde{h}_i)$ is affine over $D(h_i)$, then is $X$ also affine.

Comment: More generally, is there a nice way to show that a given quasi-projective variety is affine? I have been trying to manufacture an explicit isormorphism from the variety $X$ to a (hopefuly affine) variety made up of the $D(\tilde{h}_i)$ in some way, but the computations are getting messy...